# Inject Google Guava Hashmultimap using Spring

Tags: java, spring, guava

Is it possible to provide an example of creating a `Multimap<String, String>` using Spring?

I am curious in looking at how it would be done in the application context XML file.

Comment: Not easy, since the `Multimap` classes are not javabean-compliant. What sort of thing would you *like* to able to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) is deprecated in favor of [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), so I will answer regarding Guava.

I will use this Bean class:

```
public class Bean{
    private Multimap<String, String> map;
    public void setMap(Multimap<String, String> map){
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

The only Guava Multimap factory method you can easily wire (with XML only) is the [`Multimaps.forMap(existingMap)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#forMap%28java.util.Map%29) method. Here's the XML:

```
<bean class="foo.bar.Bean">
    <property name="map">
        <bean class="com.google.common.collect.Multimaps"
            factory-method="forMap">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="java.util.HashMap" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you want one of the more complicated [`Supplier`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html)-based methods in the [`Multimaps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) class, you will have to create the Suppliers as Java Classes. If you just want a primitive instantiating `Supplier`, you can create that as a Spring `FactoryBean`:

```
public class SupplierFactoryBean<T> extends AbstractFactoryBean<Supplier<T>>{

    private final Class<T> type;
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;

    public SupplierFactoryBean(final Class<T> type){
        this.type = type;
        this.supplier = new Supplier<T>(){
            @Override
            public T get(){
                try{
                    return type.newInstance();
                } catch(final Exception e){
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType(){ return type; }

    @Override
    protected Supplier<T> createInstance() throws Exception{
        return supplier;
    }
}
```

(You may also model the above as a Supplier class without a FactoryBean, the Spring usage remains the same. Just make sure it returns a new instance for every call.)

Now you can wire the more complicated methods. Example:

```
<bean class="foo.bar.Bean">
    <property name="map">
        <bean class="com.google.common.collect.Multimaps"
            factory-method="newSetMultimap">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="java.util.HashMap" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="foo.bar.SupplierFactoryBean">
                    <constructor-arg value="java.util.TreeSet" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

Both examples above use static factory methods. Here's the corresponding chapter in the Spring Reference: [**3.3.2.2 Instantiation with a static factory method**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method)