# Spring beans: multiple values for a single map entry

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a dependent bean definition mapped something like this:

```
<bean id="MyFieldFilterFactory" class="xyz.project.FieldFilterFactory" scope="prototype" >
<property name="parameters">
  <map>
    <entry key="mycheckBoxfield_" value-ref="myCheckBoxFilterFields" />
  </map>
</property>
```

```
<bean id="myCheckBoxFilterFields" class="xyz.myFilterDefinitionClass" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dependentField" value="FirstName_"/>
</bean>
```

Now I need to define multiple dependentFields for the entry key mycheckBoxfield. I was hoping to do something like

```
<bean id="myCheckBoxFilterFields" class="xyz.myFilterDefinitionClass" scope="prototype">
    <property name="dependentField" value="FirstName_"/>
    <property name="dependentField" value="LastName_"/>
    <property name="dependentField" value="MiddleName_"/>
</bean>
```

or may be multiple value-refs for the given entry so that I can create multiple beans that are dependent with the same entry key.

But figured this is not allowed. Being a beginner with spring-beans, I am not sure how can I achieve this. I basically need to have multiple fields to dependent upon the entry key. If this does not make any sense, I would be glad to provide more inputs.
Thank you.

Comment: What you're looking for sounds like a multi-map. Try exploring com.google.common.collect.Multimaps Here's a nice stackoverflow answer's link which might help you- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625880/2780757

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject Google Guava Hashmultimap using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622821/inject-google-guava-hashmultimap-using-spring)